# Titanium appcelerator clear all global variables when logging out

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

Any appcelerator titanium developper here :) ? On my app mobile i have a classic login/logout pages, when login i have a global variable "Alloy.Globals.user" created which contains all user objects (name, photo etc ...), i have also some app properties (Ti.app.properties).
When a personne logout from the app, i want to destroy all globals variables and properties, actually i did :

```
$.logout.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    Alloy.Globals.user = {};
    Alloy.Globals.user = null;
    Ti.app.properties.removeProperty("property_name")
})
```

But if another user log in on the same device, sometimes previous user informations still displayed as new user profile.

How should i handle this please?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't store anything in globals. It is possible but bad practice. You can use a `lib` and store the information there.

But that said, resetting the global variable should do the trick. However, your `addEventListener` doesn't do anything at all. What is it supposed to do?

`addEventListener` requires 2 properties. The first is which event to listen to and the second the function to call when that specific event fires. Assuming `$.logout` is a button, you should do `$.logout.addEventListener('click',function(){});`

Also, if you have displayed the user information in, say, a window. You need to remove that window and clear it from memory. The displayed information isn't removed when you remove the information itself. It basically is a rendering of what you had at the time it rendered. So remove any UI element that displays information and remove all data property when you want the user to logout. That should do the trick.

**How to use `lib`?**

`lib` is a folder inside `app`. If you don't have it, create it. In that folder you can create files that "do stuff". Variables inside a lib file are stored during the session just like a global variable. Only, it isn't on the global namespace.

`lib` files are `commonjs` files. You can include lib files using `require('myLibFile')` without adding the `.js` extension. Don't store the result on a `Global` either, but just require it wherever you need it and the variables will be there.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot the click of the event listener, yes i have a click on this event (i will modify post) , anyway thanks for your response that helps me a lot i think, could you just explain me to use "lib" and store informations there?, thank you

Comment: added it! Google for how commonjs works if you don't know ;)